# Maven - java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind <null>:8080

Tags: maven

I'm getting this error while running this Maven command

```
mvn verify tomcat7:run-war
```

My pom uses 'tomcat maven plugin' and 'surefire plugin', both work ok, e.g if I prompt
 `mvn verify` or even `mvn tomcat7:run-war` I get the job done well.

Comment: You probably have an old instance still running.

Comment: I think it's been shutting down but not on time..  that is the last line called by verify phase : Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] then starts the tomcat7:run-war's calls [INFO] >>> tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run-war (default-cli) > package

Comment: Something else is definitively there. If it is Java `jps` will help you find them.

Answer (score 0):

> java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind :8080

means that another application is listening on port 8080.

You can check which process is using this port by lsof command, e.g. sudo lsof -i:8080. Then stop or kill it.

If won't help finding application running on the same port, the common mistake is the Tomcat misconfiguration.

For example by default Tomcat listens on port 8005 for SHUTDOWN command and if you set another Connector to listen on the same port, you'll get port conflict.

So please double check in server.xml whether these ports are different:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Connector port="8983" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
```

Comment: Dahar, thanks a lot for your answer... I had a look at this file 'server.xml' and tried what you said but nothing changed... I can say the port has been closed before because I tested getting access on the browser and after while it stopped working so it's been shutdown.